# AWS: IAM Policy for CodePipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

No matter how open an IAM policy I give to my CodePipeline role, my CodeBuild step always fails with Access Denied in the DOWNLOAD_SOURCE phase. The build works fine when I run manually from CodeBuild.

I have literally granted this policy to the CodePipeline service role, and the pipeline still fails:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem? Where should I be looking to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first place I'd look is your CodeBuild service role, make sure it has something like the following in the policy:

```
{
      "Sid": "S3GetObjectPolicy",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectVersion"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
```

Comment: Thanks! That's so weird... so the codebuild service role had to have the permissions and not the codepipeline role? Did my manual executions of codebuild work because they were being executed by my AWS account and not the codebuild service role?

Comment: This generally happens when you have a CodeBuild project already and you integrate it to the CodePipeline project. The Codebuild now does not download the sources from CodeCommit/Github repo. Instead, it will try to dowload the source artifact created in the codepipeline bucket in S3. So, you will need to provide permissions to the CodeBuild role to access the codepipline bucket in S3.